# How to make img stick to bottom while scaling up to fill parent?

Tags: html, css

I want to have an image stick to the bottom while scaling up to fill its parent and maintaining its aspect ratio.

I know how to do it with a background-image but I want it to be an `<img>`.
The size of the parent is unknown.

Is there a way to do it without JavaScript?

The snippet shows what I  want.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: contain;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x50" alt="">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25" alt="">
</div>
What I want:
<div style="background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/25x50)">
</div>
<div style="background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/50x25)">
</div>
```

Comment: stick to bottom of window?

Comment: stick to bottom of container.

Comment: Well, I believe assigning `vertical-align : bottom` might work

Comment: Should not take to much research effort to find out that object-fit has a corresponding property, https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#propdef-object-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [**`object-position`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) together with `object-fit`:

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-size: contain;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/25x50" alt="">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x25" alt="">
</div>
What I want:
<div style="background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/25x50)">
</div>
<div style="background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/50x25)">
</div>
```